# cannot write into file after getting results from mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have the following codes to get some results from MySql and write them into a file. But noting is written into the file, am I missing anything?

```
import MySQLdb as dbapi
import sys
import csv
import xlwt
dbServer='127.0.0.1'
dbPass='Mydatabases#0'
dbSchema='myblog'
dbUser='root'
out='C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/outfile.txt'
dbQuery="SELECT link,repo_name,dataset_id,COALESCE (title, 'No data has been provided'),COALESCE (description, 'No data has been provided') FROM myblog.testseprator";   
db=dbapi.connect(host=dbServer,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPass)
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute(dbQuery)
result=cur.fetchall() 
with open('out','w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t')
    for row in result:
        writer.writerow(row)        
db.close();
```

Comment: Did you try logging to console in your `for` loop? This makes sure your db query returns results from database.

Comment: @ShuwnYuanTee it does return results

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code in order to get your desired output:

```
    import os
    import pymysql
    from pandas import DataFrame
    def connect_to_database(host,user,password,db,query):
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                         user=user,
                         password=password,                             
                         db=db,
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                c=cursor.execute(query)
                df = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())  
        finally:
           connection.close()
        return df
        #this will return a pandas dataframe which you can directly convert to csv
```

Once you get the dataframe you can use pandas's to_csv to convert to csv file. Suppose you called the function and got the result back into "result"

```
    path='C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\'
    result.to_csv(os.path.join(path+r'output.csv'))
    #this will convert the result dataframe into file called "output"
```

Comment: Also, where should I put the query? @Anisha

Comment: thanks, but  using the codes that you suggested generates output file like this: ,"COALESCE (description, 'No data has been provided')","COALESCE (title, 'No data has been provided')",dataset_id,link,repo_name
0,"Thi(T2DM), and whether attacks, compared to a p2DM.... it seems it cannot separate fields also a part of my query is there! @Anisha